# extract information from a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary where keys are product codes and values below each keys are some specifics of the products (e.g. weight, colour, price, etc.). 
Now let's say that the code loops through a list of product codes that I have. 
I want to check that the code (called *myKey* in the code below) is in my dictionary, in which case I also want to extract some properties (let's say just colour and price in my case). I am trying the following but without success:

```
var myColour = myDictionary
    .Where(x => myDictionary.Keys.Contains(myKey))
    .Select(x => x.Value.Colour);

var myPrice = myDictionary
    .Where(x => myDictionary.Keys.Contains(myKey))
    .Select(x => x.Value.Price);
```

I don't have any error, but I simply don't see the results stored in the variables myColor and myPrice.

What is the right syntax for my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be over complicating things.  The following should do what you want.

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
    var theValue = myDictionary[myKey].SomeProperty
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
MyValueType myValue;
if(myDictionary.TryGetValue(myKey, out myValue)){
    Console.Out.WriteLine(myValue.Colour);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(myValue.Price);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing this example that clarifies how to use .TryGetValue(). It helps a lot.